flood fill VDM brushes?
I'm doing sculpting for 3D printing so I need real geometry that's manifold.
Is there a technique to flood fill a tiled displacement/texture onto a portion of a mesh?
I've tried sculpting mode with a tiled vdm brush but that displaces an existing mesh.
I have to by trial and error add huge amounts of polygons until I get something that only poorly resembles what I want to print. It also contains far more geometry than is needed.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Probably, with Geometry Nodes and/or some deform modifiers. You might also try the remesh modifier.
